# Quickly convert raw data to hex string in c++

Tags: c++, qt, char

I'm reading data from a file and trying to display the raw data as 2 digit hex strings.

I'm using the Qt framework, specifically the QTextEdit.

I've tried a bunch of different approaches and have almost accomplished what I want it to do, however it has some unexpected errors I don't know anything about.

Currently this is my implementation:

1) Read in the data:

```
ifstream file (filePath, ios::in|ios::binary|ios::ate);
if (file.is_open())
{
    size = file.tellg();
    memblock = new char [size+1];
    file.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    file.read(memblock, size);
    file.close();
}
```

2) Create a single QString that will be used (because QTextEdit requires a QString):

```
QString s;
```

3) Loop through the array appending each successive character to the QString s.

```
int count = 0;
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    count++;;
    s.append(QString::number(memblock[i], 16).toUpper());
    s.append("\t");
    if (count == 16)
    {
        s.append("\n");
        count -= 16;
    }
}
```

Now this works fine, except when it reaches a character `FF`, it appears as `FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`

So my main questions are:

1. **Why do only the 'FF' characters appear as 'FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF' instead?**
2. **Is there a way to convert the char data to base 16 strings without using QString::number?**

I want this implementation to be as fast as possible, so if something like sprintf could work, please let me know, as I would guess that might be faster that QString::number.

Comment: Why not do this natively in C++ rather than using QString? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10599068/how-do-i-print-bytes-as-hexadecimal  You can do it in C++ then just shove it in a QString?

Comment: This also looks like it would be much faster, thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`QString` can't be used for binary data. You should use `QByteArray` instead. It can be easily created from `char*` buffer and can be easily converted to hex string using `toHex`.

```
QByteArray array(memblock, size);
textEdit->setText(QString(array.toHex()));
```

Comment: Okay this seems to be the best answer.  I didn't know QByteArray even existed and it seems like it's much more suited for this kind of thing. Now what if I want to append other characters to the QString, like '\t' in between each 2-digit hex value, and '\n' after 16 of them? It looks like I can do QString.append(QByteArray), but not QString.append(QByteArray[i]).  Any help?

Comment: After you have hex representation, it's better to work with it using QString. So you have `QString s = array.toHex();`. Now you can use `QString::insert` to insert characters into string directly (but calculate inserting index carefully), or you can extract parts of original string using `midRef` and append them into new string using `append`.

Comment: Very nice I didn't know about that.  What would you say the advantages are as opposed to looping and doing QString.append(array.at())? Would it be any faster?

Comment: To copy 2 digits you need 2 calls of `array.at` (and `append`) or 1 call of `midRef` (and `append`). So I guess using `midRef` will be slightly faster.

Answer (score 3):

[`QString::number`](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#number) doesn't have an overload that takes a `char`, so your input is being promoted to an `int`; consequently you're seeing the effects of sign extension. You should be seeing similar behavior for any input greater than `0x7F`.

Try casting the data prior to calling the function.

```
s.append(QString::number(static_cast<unsigned char>(memblock[i]), 16).toUpper());
```

Comment: Putting one char at a time is very slow. QString can be converted from `char*` buffer. But QString can't contain binary data.

Comment: @Riateche Umm, he's not putting binary data into the QString, he's converting the bytes to their hex representations (strings), and appending that. But I agree that your QByteArray method is better; I only attempted to answer his question.