# How to compress data on the fly using Microchip TCP/IP Stack

Tags: embedded, pic, microchip

I implement gzip on our [Microchip TCP/IP](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=2680&dDocName=en537041) embedded web server to compress static web resources (html, js, and css files) - The files get gzipped automagically when we upload the web site to the Microchip server.

However, I have a web page that is generated on the fly (it's not a static html page) and this page contains a lot of data (~2MB).

To speed up the download time (for the client), I would like to gzip the data prior to sending it to the client. Is this possible? Or are we limited to compressing only static files?

Answer (score 0):

Does the embedded web server do the compressing of the static files, or do you compress, then upload? In case of the latter, you can probably port the [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/) library. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538586/how-to-compress-a-buffer-with-zlib) for details on how to compress a buffer on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Dinamic gzipping will take a lot of time. I suggest you to have a static gzipped web-page skeleton with dinamically loading content:

1) on client request you response the static gzipped web-page;

2) this page has javascript code, so the client runs it;

3) javascript code uses [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first) to send a request on specific web-page (/ajax.html, for example);

4) on this page request you response the dinamic content only, uncompressed;

5) on this answer, javascript analizes it and places the data to the correct place on page;

6) profit.